# Show/Hide DIVs That Have Multiple Attribute Values Based On Dropdown Option Value "jQuery Filter Method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show/hide multiple services that each have a custom attribute called data-serviceregion that each may or may not have multiple values according to the single value of each of the dropdown select option

```
<form class="book-now">
<select name="region" id="region">
<option value="">choose region</option>
<option data-regionid="70" value="region-1">region-1</option>
<option data-regionid="71" value="region-2">region-2</option>
</select>


<div id="bookingservices" style="display: none;">

<div data-serviceregion="70,71" class="service-outer" style="display: block; width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;text-align:center;">
<div class="service-name"><h5>Cs a c</h5></div>
<div class="service-price">5000.00&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div data-serviceregion="71" class="service-outer" style="display: block;width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
<div class="service-name"><h5>Re a c</h5></div>
<div class="service-price">2000.00&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div data-serviceregion="70" class="service-outer" style="display: block;width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
<div class="service-name"><h5>Cs a h</h5></div>
<div class="service-price">5000.00&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

So basically in this line "jQuery('.service-outer').filter(function() {" i'm filtering each of the .service-outer DIVs taking the value of each of their attribute then splitting it into array

Then i'm using inArray method to check if the value of the dropdown option is in the array that i've previously created and finally showing or hiding it depending on the condition that it's in the array or not

Note: i'm appending the variable for debug reason I figured it will be useful when you try the code
The problem is when executing the code it's taking only the first div attribute value and not each div and then only showing the remaining two DIVs

Second Note: I've tried using filter method to compare single value of regionid with single value of data-serviceregion and it was working for only services that have one number

```
jQuery('select[name="region"]').change(function(){

    var region = jQuery(this).val();

    var regionid = jQuery(this).find(':selected').data("regionid");

    if(region != "") {
        jQuery("#bookingservices").show();  

        jQuery('.service-outer').filter(function() {
  var serregs = jQuery(this).data("serviceregion");
  var serreg = serregs.split(",");
            if ( jQuery.inArray(regionid, serreg)!=-1 ) {
            jQuery(this).show();
    jQuery("#bookingservices").append('<p>'+serreg+'</p>');
            }
    else {
    jQuery("#bookingservices").append(serreg);
    jQuery(this).hide();

    }  


        });
    }else{
        jQuery("#bookingservices").hide();  
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get a single value(on  second and third div's) with out `,` so while splitting it produces error. that's why your code is not working.

Try like this.

```js
jQuery('select[name="region"]').change(function(){

  var region = jQuery(this).val();

  var regionid = jQuery(this).find(':selected').data("regionid")+'';

  if(region != "") {
    jQuery("#bookingservices").show();  
    jQuery('.service-outer').filter(function() {
      var serregs = jQuery(this).data("serviceregion")+''; //here you get a single value(on  second and third divs) with out , so while splitting it produces error.
      var serreg = serregs.split(",");
      if ( jQuery.inArray(regionid, serreg)!=-1 ) {
        jQuery(this).show();
        jQuery("#bookingservices").append('<p>'+serreg+'</p>');
      }
      else {
        jQuery(this).hide();
      }  


    });
  }else{
    jQuery("#bookingservices").hide();  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="book-now">
  <select name="region" id="region">
    <option value="">choose region</option>
    <option data-regionid="70" value="region-1">region-1</option>
    <option data-regionid="71" value="region-2">region-2</option>
  </select>


  <div id="bookingservices" style="display: none;">

    <div data-serviceregion="70,71" class="service-outer" style="display: block; width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;text-align:center;">
      <div class="service-name"><h5>Cs a c</h5></div>
      <div class="service-price">5000.00&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div data-serviceregion="71" class="service-outer" style="display: block;width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
      <div class="service-name"><h5>Re a c</h5></div>
      <div class="service-price">2000.00&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div data-serviceregion="70" class="service-outer" style="display: block;width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
      <div class="service-name"><h5>Cs a h</h5></div>
      <div class="service-price">5000.00&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The final magic touch i was missing, I knew i was close, Thank you very much, Awesome work.